# Get the lowest number from an Array

Tags: java, arrays

For my programming class I need to write a method where the code prints the fastest and the second fastest runner.

This is what I've got:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
class Marathon { 
    public static void main (String[] arguments){ `
        `String[] names ={ 
                "Alex", "Clair", "Sarah", "Andy", "Anna", "Bob"
        }; 
        int[] times ={ 
                341, 273, 278, 329, 445, 402, 
        }; 
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) { 
            System.out.println(names[i]+ ": " + times[i]); 
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get it to show only the fastest person (lowest number) and the second fastest person (second lowest number).

Comment: How would find just the fastest?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to find the fastest runner

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
class Marathon { 
    public static void main (String[] arguments){         
        HashMap<String, Integer>namez = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        namez.put("Alex", 341 );
        namez.put("Clair",273 );
        namez.put("Sarah",278);
        namez.put("Andy",329);
        namez.put("Anna",445 );
        namez.put("Bob",402);
        Integer min = Collections.min(namez.values());
        namez.containsValue(min);
        for (Entry<String, Integer>entry: namez.entrySet()){
            if(entry.getValue()==min){
                System.out.println(entry.getKey()+": "+entry.getValue());
                String key = entry.getKey();
            }               
        }     
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here is actually the way that finds fastest and the second fastest person from your list. It only outputs their names, which are Clair and Sarah. I hope it helps.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
class Marathon { 
    public static void main (String[] arguments){
        HashMap<Integer, String>namez = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        namez.put(341,"Alex");
        namez.put(273,"Clair");
        namez.put(278, "Sarah");
        namez.put(329,"Andy");
        namez.put(445,"Anna");
        namez.put(402, "Bob");
        ArrayList<Integer> timez = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        timez.add(341);
        timez.add(273);
        timez.add(278);
        timez.add(329);
        timez.add(445);
        timez.add(402);
        Collections.sort(timez);
        System.out.println(namez.get(timez.get(0)));
        System.out.println(namez.get(timez.get(1)));        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the most compact way to do it:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create the mapping:
        TreeMap<Integer, String> timeToNameMapping = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();
        timeToNameMapping.put(341, "Alex");
        timeToNameMapping.put(273, "Clair");
        timeToNameMapping.put(278, "Sarah");
        timeToNameMapping.put(329, "Andy");
        timeToNameMapping.put(445, "Anna");
        timeToNameMapping.put(402, "Bob");

        //Get the keys from the above mapping.
        //Since it is a TreeMap, the keys are sorted
        List<Integer> times = new ArrayList<>(timeToNameMapping.keySet());

        //Print the result
        System.out.println("First: " + timeToNameMapping.get(times.get(0)));
        System.out.println("Second: " + timeToNameMapping.get(times.get(1)));
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
First: Clair
Second: Sarah
```

**Explanation:**
I am using the reverse mapping, as this enables you to just sort all the keys, and then map the first two elements of the sorted list to the names in the TreeMap (given a runtime the TreeMap above will tell you the name of the runner for that time). TreeMaps are already ordered, but since they keys in the Map are in a *TreeSet* we cannot use index on it to get the two first elements. That is why I convert the keySet() to an ArrayList (which allows for indexing).

To elaborate on dictionaries (Maps):
Generally when using Lists you use the get() method to get a specific element. For Lists like ArrayList and LinkedList the get() method takes an integer (an index value) and returns the element that are at that position in the list.
Maps are a bit different: Maps make a correlation between a *key* and a *value*. In the above example if I give the map the key 341, then it will give me the value "Alex". The get() method on a Map therefore takes a key of type K (in this case an Integer, but it can be any kind of object actually) and returns a value of type V (in this case a String, but can also be any object). The type of the key and value are determined when creating the Map (in this case K, V = Integer, String). The concept of telling the map exactly what types are being used are called generics.

Answer (score -1):

You want to sort the array first and then print out the first two in the array. Because it is for your class I wont give you the code that you need but I gave you the perfect hint all you have to do is google how to sort the array and call on first two. Google Keyswords "Java Sort Array"